# The procedure entry point EnumerateLoadedModulesW64 cound not be located in the dynamic link library dbghelp.dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++

all, i tried to use Visual Leak Detector in my MFC project, and when i tried to debug the program, i got this error, whats this?

cheers

daiyue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a DLL Hell problem.  This function only exists in DbgHelp.dll version 5.1 and greater.  You can get an up-to-date version by downloading the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx).  It is included in the Windows SDK lately, unfortunately.  That's another kind of DLL Hell.

Do ping the support for Visual Leak Detector, they should have deployed a correct version of the DLL.

Comment: Sorry, I don't support VLD.  If you don't want to use the solution I proposed then talk to the vendor instead.

Comment: thx for the help, i installed the Debugging tools, and the problem still exists

Comment: Use a tool like SysInternals' Process Explorer to find out where VLD picked up its copy of DbgHelp.dll.  A likely place is c:\windows\system32, a location that DTFW doesn't try to touch.  A crappy installer is a likely source of getting an old version of that DLL copied there.  Look at version numbers with Windows Explorer.

Comment: i found 2 dbghelp.dll, one in system32, another one is in system32\dllcache; the version number is 5.1.2600.5512. the version of dbghelp.dll of VLD installation is 6.11.1.404.

Comment: i copied over the new version of dbghelp.dll into my debug folder of my project, and it works.